# gcc: constexpr functions in C23?

Tags: c, gcc, constexpr, c23

Playing around with `constexpr` with GCC v14.0 (which should be close to the soon to be released GCC v13.1), I compiled the following module:

```cpp
constexpr int f (int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}

constexpr const int x[] = { f(1) };
```

with `gcc -std=c2x -c foo.c -O2`
but GCC throws:

```
foo.c:1:1: error: 'constexpr' requires an initialized data declaration
   1 | constexpr int f (int x)
     | ^~~~~~~~~
[...f'up errors due to the one above...]
```

According to [`constexpr` in C23 proposal (pdf)](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2851.pdf) this should be correct syntax. That PDF doesn't come with any examples though, so what I am missing here?

GCC can deal with `constexpr` since C++11, so implementing it in the C frontend should be known and mature technology.

Comment: `constexpr` in C23 won't work the same as in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposal [N2851](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2851.pdf) that you linked was not accepted.

Only [N3018](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3018.htm) has been incorporated into the C23 draft and this proposal does not include `constexpr` on functions, only on objects.

So with the draft

```
constexpr int x[] = { 3 };
```

and

```
constexpr int i = 1;
constexpr int x[] = { i + 2 };
static int y[] = { i + 2 };
```

are allowed, but you can't call a function in the initializer or mark a function `constexpr`.

You don't need to add `const` by the way. `constexpr` implies a top-level `const`.

Comment: Ok, so WG14 messed this one up... What a missed opportunity!

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts It seems they had several implementation concerns and want to collect experience first in with a TS. See TS proposal [N2976](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2976.pdf)) and minutes [N2941](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2941.pdf) for discussion of the N2851 proposal. There are a few issues that the implementation might have in C that are not present in C++, e.g. an array becoming a VLA depending on implementation limits.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts  I would also expect that they don't want to effectively require a compiler to be able to fully interpret the language, like current C++ `constexpr` functions require (although N2851 only proposed a subset about equivalent to C++11's `constexpr`).

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts Or rather we should be grateful that they aren't just smoking, tripping and including every single feature that someone proposed... there's still an ambition to keep the language well-defined, useful, portable without thousands of cases of poorly-defined behavior. As a comparison, were we to make a list of all poorly-defined behavior in C++, the summary list would be much longer than the ISO standard itself. That's simply not a desirable state of affairs for a programming language which is to be used in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

Opposite to C++ In C the storage class specifier `constexpr` may be used only for object definitions.

So this function declaration

```
constexpr int f (int x)
{
    return x + 2;
}
```

is incorrect and hence the compiler issues an error.

The `constexpr` storage class specifier is included in the C23 Standard according to the following document

```
N3018 constexpr for Object Definitions
```