# What new types and operations can take place in a constexpr in C23?

Tags: c, constexpr, compile-time-constant, c23

C23 added a keyword `constexpr` which can be used to define objects as compile-time constants instead of enumerations or macros. For example:

```cpp
constexpr int x = 10;
constexpr int y = x+10; // Valid

switch (some_var) {
    case y: // Valid
        // ...
}
static int z = y; // Valid
```

Previously only integer constants (`sizeof()` or `enum` or literal values such as `10`) or addresses of global/`static` objects could be treated as compile/translation-time constants and a handful of arithmetic operations could be performed on them at compile-time.

Are there any new operations and types can be handled in a `constexpr` expression in C23? What are the limitations?

Answer (score 1):

#### Compound literals

`constexpr` can be used to qualify compound literal:

> A compound literal with storage-class specifier constexpr is a compound literal constant. A compound literal constant is a constant expression with the type and value of the unnamed object.

Before C23 there was no support for compile-time constant (Or even `static`) compound literals even if all their members were compile-time constant:

```c
static int x = (int){0}; // Non-portable
```

```cpp
static int x = (constexpr int){0}; // Valid C23
```

#### `struct` and `union`

> Starting from a structure or union constant, the member-access `.` operator may be used to form a named constant [...].

`constexpr` can be combined with a `struct` or `union` to create a compile-time constant object. The members may be read **at compile time:**

```cpp
constexpr struct {
    int x;
} s = {10};
static int x = s.x; // Valid
```

This does not permit [compile-time type-punning](https://langdev.stackexchange.com/q/3653/38) though:

> If the member-access operator `.` accesses a member of a union constant, the accessed member shall be the same as the member that is initialized by the union constant's initializer.

#### Arrays

There is no way to access the value of any array member at compile time:

> The array-subscript `[]` and member-access `->` operator, the address `&` and indirection `*` unary operators, and pointer casts may be used in the creation of an address constant, but the value of an object shall not be accessed by use of these operators.

But those operators **can** be used to generate an **address** of one of the array members as a compile-time constant.

#### Functions

C++-style `constexpr` functions are [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76079850/16217248). As such no function call can be used in a `constexpr` expression.

#### Unsupported operations

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.